# RavenDB Stopwords

Tags: lucene.net, ravendb

I am looking to add a few new stopwords to the StandardAnalizer in RavenDB.

My document structure has a full name.  I am using RavenDB to back an Autocomplete.  When a user types in 'Mr' we don't want any results.  I thought about just filtering the words in my jQuery script, but wanted to see about options in RavenDB.

{
  Name: "Mr. John Smith"
}

It would also be nice to have the stopwords list as a single document in RavenDB, but a config file is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to define a custom analyzer for this to work.